# Storing a sexp evaluation, so it can be called elsewhere (Emacs Lisp)

Tags: emacs, lisp, eval

I am programming a lot in the scratch buffer, and often I evaluate some expression at one point, and would like to evaluate the same expression somewhere else (without having to write a function for it).

One example is when I wanted to test `(looking-at "\\<")`, to see if I am looking at the beginning of a word. When using `eval-last-sexp` it evaluates the thing before `(point)`.

So, this means that I can test:

`(looking-at "\\<")<(point)>someword`

but that I cannot test expressions before `(point)`:

`someword<(point)>(looking-at "\\<")`

In order to test this, I actually did something like:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (when (looking-at "\\<") (message "t"))
)
```

and then call it somewhere else at point (sometimes, when I would test a lot I would even bind it to a key).

It is actually not hard to come up with an answer to "how does `(looking-at)` behave", but the question I am interested in is if it would be possible to store `the-last-user-called-sexp` somewhere, so that it can be invoked elsewhere in the buffer by using some function like:

```
(defun invoke-last-sexp (sexp)
 (interactive)
 (evaluate the last sexp) ; maybe even (call-interactively) is sometimes needed
)
```

Comment: Another good way to test out how expressions behave in different contexts is to use the Elisp REPL, which lets you evaluate expressions in the context of any other buffer. Type `M-x ielm` to enter it, followed by `C-c C-b` to change the working buffer. The working buffer setting is "sticky", so you can switch to it and move point and mark around, then switch back to `ielm` and try out some more code, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also like to be able to quickly eval a form regardless of where i
am. For that, I have a macro inspired from
[magnars](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d.git)' configuration.

```
(defmacro create-simple-keybinding-command (name key)
  `(progn (defmacro ,name (&rest fns)
            (list 'global-set-key (kbd ,key)
                  `(lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     ,@fns)))

          (defmacro ,(intern (concat (symbol-name name) "e")) (&rest fns)
            (list 'global-set-key (kbd ,key)
                  `(lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     (message "%s"
                              (progn
                                ,@fns)))))))
```

For example, you eval

```
(create-simple-keybinding-command f9 "<f9>")
```

and you have two macros `f9` and `f9e`. `f9e` is like `f9` except that
it shows return value in minibuffer. In your case you eval

```
(f9e (looking-at "\\<"))
```

Now the form is evaluated everytime you press <kbd>f9</kbd>.

You might want to look at my emacs configuration [here](https://github.com/thisirs/dotemacs/blob/master/init-bindings.el) where I have a couple macros doing more or less the same thing.

Comment: Nice. I went through your whole emacs file.

Answer (score 3):

You might like to use the command bound to the `M-:` key.

Comment: I am at least also aware of `C-M-x`, but all these evaluaters do not work when I would like to evaluate an expression at the end of the buffer, while point is at the start of the buffer?

Comment: `M-:` evaluates an expression read from the minibuffer regardless of the location of point.

Comment: A way then would be to kill-save the expression, and use M-: eval with a yank?

Comment: Yes, and then you use the input history to evaludate it again.